# how to handle PhoneGap sql storage result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova

In the PhoneGap API http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage
There is a SQLResultSet example of how to handle sql SELECT results.. now

In my code I have something like this

```
id=17
if(recordExists(id)){
.. do something
}
```

recordExists function is checking within local db to see if the record exists. How can I return a true/false result from this function? so that it can be used within condition

```
function recordExists(id){
try {
    mydb.transaction(
      function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(
                'SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id='+id, [],null,null); 
      });
  } catch(e) {
    alert("Problem : " + e.message);
    return;
  }
}
```

Normally in PG examples there are callback functions. Obviously I can't return a result from  the callback function. Is there a way to use it as in PHP where you would have something like

```
$result = recordExists();
```

One possible solution i see as a workaround is on app initialization select all records to a variable and recordExists function would operate on it. But i would prefer to operate with sql on this table instead..

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically put the "do something" in the callback function.